# Why git diff uses symbolic a/b and +/-

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

The git command:
**git diff**

Returns back some informations.
First ligne associates stage to letter **a** and working space to **b**.

But later we learn that in fact staging area will be **-** and working space will be **+**

I wonder why not just use a/b symbolic?

thank you

Comment: Do you have some particular objection to the `a/` and `b/` prefixes? Because if you do, note that `git diff` can be told to use any prefix you like (`--src-prefix=a/` and `--dst-prefix=b/` are the defaults), or no prefix at all (`--no-prefix`).

Comment: Not espacially, just a question